# primeng datatable template header with scrollable

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, primeng

I have a datatable

```
<p-dataTable ... > 
        <p-column field="name" header="Name" [style]="{'width':'250px'}"> 
               <template pTemplate type="header">
            <mycomponent> </mycomponent>
            </template>
    </p-column>
    ...
    </p-dataTable>
```

Mycomponent  basically contains a button when clicked open a hidden div.
Which act like a modal and has absolute positioning.
See the picture below
[image: https://s16.postimg.org/4ugtpunud/primeng_scrollable.png]
It works fine but if I add the scrollable option

```
<p-dataTable ...  scrollable="true" scrollHeight="200px" scrollWidth="75%">
```

then the modal box is hidden like in the picture. 
I don't manage to put it on top.
I tried with z-index but it doesn't work.
Could you see why I have this different behaviour?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use appendTo="body" in your p-multiSelect tag. This will add the dropdown to your column header.

Eg :

```
<p-column field="Description" ...>
<template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
  <p-multiSelect appendTo="body" ... ></p-multiSelect>
</template>
```